# Exporting a dictionary with multiple values and importing them for later use without using pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, import, export

I am making a program to export, import, and display employee information such as SSN, full name, phone number, salary, and email.
I use a dictionary with SSN as the key so I can look up employee information by searching for them with their SSN.

I tried to exporting the dictionary to a json file which seems to work.

I tried importing it and I get an error message:  I tried this code after importing os:

```
    CWD = os.getcwd()
    JSON_CONFIG_FILE_PATH = '%s/%s' % (CWD, 'data.json')

    CONFIG_PROPERTIES = {}

    try:
        with open(JSON_CONFIG_FILE_PATH) as data_file:
            CONFIG_PROPERTIES = json.load(data_file)
   print(CONFIG_PROPERTIES)
```

I got an error message

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 28 (char 27)

Comment: Since you already have dictionary in the desired format, why not dump the dictionary into json instead of CSV. Dumping to json and reading from json is straight-forward. is there any specific requirement to use CSV? If not then look into `json` module.

Comment: Can you please attach a sample json. Most likely there is some error with the json data.

Comment: Got it to work.  Thanks for the input.  I was just entering 1's for the entries to speed up testing for the application.  Once I entered entries like phone numbers and names as it was intended it worked.  I don't know why putting down just single one's didn't work but hey, it works when I put down the intended type of info.

Comment: Great. That's good to hear.

Comment: Just a thought addressing the reason of error. Json allows unique keys just like dictionaries. In case there are multiple keys set as 1, it will throw error. However without the json data we can't say for sure, if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the json module to import and export.

```
import json             # add this to your imports
data = {"test":"test"}  # assume data is your dictionary, and make sure the file 'data.json' exists.

# Import

data = json.load(open('data.json')  

# Export

with open('data.json', 'w') as JSON_Exporter:
    json.dump(data, JSON_Exporter)
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your comment on JSON_Exporter.  I had just been scratching my head trying to figure out how to update the json dictionary without these error I've been getting.  Thank you so much!